# How to hide INFO messages from LocalServiceTestHelper when running GAE/J test cases?

Tags: java, unit-testing, google-app-engine, testing, logging

Before deploying my GAE app, I am running several hundreds of [unit tests](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting) locally. I am using the [LocalServiceTestHelper](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting/javadoc/com/google/appengine/tools/development/testing/LocalServiceTestHelper) to use GAE services like memcache or the datastore. Setting up and tearing down the helper between tests creates a lot of log output.

*How can I re-configure [java.util.logging](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) in order to avoid [INFO messages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Level.html) caused by LocalServiceTestHelper entirely?*

```
INFO: Local Datastore initialized: 
Type: Master/Slave
Storage: In-memory
Feb 08, 2013 7:01:52 PM com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.dev.LocalTaskQueue init
INFO: LocalTaskQueue is initialized
Feb 08, 2013 7:01:52 PM com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.dev.LocalTaskQueue init
INFO: Automatic task execution is disabled.
Feb 08, 2013 7:01:52 PM org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool initialize
INFO: Job execution threads will use class loader of thread: main
Feb 08, 2013 7:01:52 PM org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler <init>
INFO: Quartz Scheduler v.null.null.null created.
Feb 08, 2013 7:01:52 PM org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore initialize
INFO: RAMJobStore initialized.
Feb 08, 2013 7:01:52 PM org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory instantiate
INFO: Quartz scheduler 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' initialized from default resource file in Quartz package: 'quartz.properties'
Feb 08, 2013 7:01:52 PM org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory instantiate
INFO: Quartz scheduler version: null.null.null
Feb 08, 2013 7:01:52 PM com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.dev.LocalTaskQueue start_
INFO: Local task queue initialized with base url http://localhost:8080
Feb 08, 2013 7:01:52 PM org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler shutdown
INFO: Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutting down.
Feb 08, 2013 7:01:52 PM org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler standby
INFO: Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED paused.
Feb 08, 2013 7:01:52 PM org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler shutdown
INFO: Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutdown complete.
```

**EDIT:**

I created the file src/test/resources/logging.properties. The file is copied to target/test-classes/ before the tests are executed. It has the following content:

```
com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.dev.level=SEVERE
org.quartz.level=WARNING
```

But I am still seeing the same log output while running the tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the logging.properties file in src/test/resources/ was well-formed, the maven-surefire-plugin was not aware of its location. As described [in another stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3939549/1769636), you have to set the java.util.logging.config.file system property when configuring the plugin. After applying this simple change everything works as expected.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <systemProperties>
      <property>
        <name>java.util.logging.config.file</name>
        <value>${project.build.directory}/test-classes/logging.properties</value>
      </property>
    </systemProperties>
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Get a copy of `logging.properties` from your `appengine-java-sdk/config/user/` folder and put it into your project's classpath, for instance `src/test/resources` folder if using maven, and start configuring your own settings from here:

```
# A default java.util.logging configuration.
# (All App Engine logging is through java.util.logging by default).
#
# To use this configuration, copy it into your application's WEB-INF
# folder and add the following to your appengine-web.xml:
# 
# <system-properties>
#   <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
# </system-properties>
#

# Set the default logging level for all loggers to WARNING
.level = WARNING
```

To configure log level for a particular package, using:

```
# Set logging level for particular package
com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.dev.level = SEVERE
org.quartz.level = WARNING
```

For a complete configuration guide, check out `lib/logging.properties` in your JRE installation folder.

Comment: Thanks! I updated my question with some more information. I already have such a file in src/test/resources. But I am still seeing the log output.. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: I'm still facing this problem. My console is full of "Local Datastore initialized" messages even though I've a logging.properties file unter src/test/resources. Any suggestions?